# Search em várias tabelas

Tags: php, pdo, query, algoritmo-de-busca

Olá, estou tentando fazer um search em 3 tabelas diferentes, vejam meu código:

```
$buscando = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM filmes WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' AND status='ativo' ORDER BY nome ASC");
```

As tabelas seriam: animes, filmes e series. Todas possuem as mesmas colunas, ou seja, seria `WHERE nome LIKE '%$busca%' AND status='ativo'` para todas.

Tentei realizar usando esse select: `SELECT * FROM animes, filmes, series`, mas não retornou nada. Poderia me ajudar?

Estruturas das minhas tabelas:

`animes`:
[image: Estrutura tabela animes]

`filmes`:
[image: Estrutura tabela filmes]

`series`:
[image: Estrutura tabela series]

Caso prefiram as imagens hospedadas:

> animes: [prntscr.com/ga9nw9](http://prntscr.com/ga9nw9) || filmes: [prnt.sc/ga9o5w](http://prnt.sc/ga9o5w) || series:
>   [prnt.sc/ga9occ](http://prnt.sc/ga9occ)

Comment: Utilize o comando **Union** do sql, que faz essas junções.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

Neste caso você pode usar a cláusula `UNION`, que junto dois ou mais resultados em um só, segue um exemplo:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            'animes' AS tabela,
            id,
            nome,
            url,
            imagem,
            status,
            null AS destaque
        FROM
            animes
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            'filmes' AS tabela,
            id,
            nome,
            url,
            imagem,
            status,
            destaque
        FROM
            filmes
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            'series' AS tabela,
            id,
            nome,
            url,
            imagem,
            status,
            null AS destaque
        FROM
            series
    ) AS t
WHERE
    t.nome LIKE '%a%'
    AND t.status='ativo'
ORDER BY
    t.nome;
```

Neste exemplo, inclui uma 'coluna' a mais indicando de qual tabela está vindo o registro (primeira coluna). Incluí todas colunas que são comum entre as 3 tabelas e incluí a coluna `destaque` que existe na tabela `filmes` e não existe na outra para exemplificar este comportamento que, neste exemplo, deixei como valor padrão nas outras tabela como `null`.

Criei este exemplo também neste fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jefqxbEkSJxArr4xQus6B2/0

Lembrando que o `UNION` exige que **todos selects devem ter exatamente a mesma quantidade de colunas com os mesmos tipos**.

Para ler mais sobre o union você pode consultar a documentação oficial do MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html

Comment: O problema é que a tabela filmes não tem a mesma quantidade de colunas que as outras duas.

Comment: Então precisa padronizar no select, edita sua pergunta com o schema das tabelas que te ajudo a montar a query ;)

Comment: animes: http://prntscr.com/ga9nw9 || filmes: https://prnt.sc/ga9o5w || series: https://prnt.sc/ga9occ

Comment: Também coloquei na pergunta, caso preferir.

Comment: Editei a resposta ajustando o exemplo ao seu schema :)

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado meu amigo!

Comment: Disponha! estamos sempre a disposição!